# Как в heatmap убрать из раскрашивания один из столбцов или иначе добиться контраста

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, plotly

У меня первый столбец всегда 100%, а остальные до 10%, поэтому градации цвета не выходит. Как поступить? [Вот такая картина.](http://joxi.ru/12Mo6zot0Xw7Er)

Рисую в Seaborn. Но буду рада и решению в Plotly.

Bывожу пивот:

```
retention_pivot = cohorts.pivot_table(index='first_visit_month',columns='cohort_lifetime',values='retention',aggfunc='sum')
```

Pисую вот так:

```
sns.set(style='white') plt.figure(figsize=(13, 9)) plt.title('Cohorts: User Retention') sns.heatmap(retention_pivot, annot=True, fmt='.1%', linewidths=1, linecolor='gray');
```

Comment: Мне кажется, надо выпилить из retention_pivot первую колонку. Что-то типа retention_pivot.drop(columns=['0']) ну или как там реально колонка называется посмотреть. Или как-то типа retention_pivot.iloc[:,1:] слайс без первой колонки взять.

Comment: Сама колонка нужна, просто пускай без цвета.. ) мне подсказали крутой выход - указать в параметрах хитмапа vmax=...  это то значение, до которого будет раскарашиваться

Comment: Ну, тогда color map надо наверное задать какую-то подходящую. Дальше я не знаю )